# Bash, Awk, Sed? Find string within file and append digits within string?

Tags: bash, loops, awk, sed

I wish to search a large text file line by line, and find each entry containing "`N:;;`" and just simply change it to "`N:07401000000;;`" and then the next occurrence of "`N:;;`" would be changed to "`N:07401000002;;`" and so on throughout the complete file of entries. Here is an example below of before and after.

Before:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000000
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000001
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000002
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000003
END:VCARD
```

After result would look like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000000;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000000
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000001;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000001
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000002;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000002
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000003;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000003
END:VCARD
```

Any help or ideas would be awesome.

> Do you want the `N` values to start at a hard-coded value and increment or just copy the value from the subsequent CELLVOICE?

Actually that is a good idea.  How about the value mentioned within CELLVOICE.

Comment: WOW, actually that is a good idea.. how about the value mentions within CELLVOICE..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the most robust and easily extensible way to do what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="END:VCARD\\s*"; FS="\n"; OFS=":" }
{
    $0 = $0 gensub(/\s+$/,"",1,RT)

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        name = gensub(/:.*/,"",1,$i)
        value = gensub(/.*:/,"",1,$i)
        n2v[name] = value
        names[i] = name
    }

    n2v["N"] = n2v["TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE"] n2v["N"]

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        name  = names[i]
        value = n2v[name]
        print name, value
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000000;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000000
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000001;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000001
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000002;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000002
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000003;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000003
END:VCARD
```

The above uses GNU awk for `gensub()`, multi-char `RS`, and `RT` and the basic (and idiomatic) idea is to split the input into records that end with `END:VCARD` and for each record first create an array (`n2v[]`) that maps field names (the part before the first `:` on each line) to their values (the part after the first `:`) and then you can just manipulate every field by it's name so you can trivially change values, rearrange the order, fill in defaults, etc. etc.

Comment: [Didge@vosser 07401]$ awk tst master07401.vcf
[Didge@vosser 07401]$ tst  master07401.vcf
bash: tst: command not found
[Didge@vosser 07401]$ bash tst  master07401.vcf
tst: line 1: BEGIN: command not found
tst: line 1: }: command not found
tst: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
tst: line 3: `    $0 = $0 gensub(/\s+$/,"",1,RT)'
[Didge@vosser 07401]$ Am I not running the script correctly?

Comment: solved it, Thanks very much ed morton, I was not reading it correctly.. my bad and am sorry for the RTFM comes to mind and you are more then welcome to slap me with a wet trout :D

Answer (score 0):

Ed Morton's answer is comprehensive, but if you're looking for a quick fix, this does the job as well:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {N=07401000000} /N:;;/ {print "N:"N++";;"; next} 1' myfile.vcf
```

Comment: How do I go about running this script against to file I wish to edit and have changed? I have tried script.sh myfile.vcf

Comment: You do `awk -f script.awk myfile.vcf`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines with `N:;;` and `CELLVOICE` occur next to each other as shown in sample, here is a solution with `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/N:;;/{N;s/.*\n(.*CELLVOICE:([0-9]+))/N:\2;;\n\1/}' ip.txt 
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000000;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000000
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000001;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000001
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000002;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000002
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:07401000003;;
TEL;TYPE=CELLVOICE:07401000003
END:VCARD
```

- If the pattern `/N:;;/` matches, get next line with `N`
- Then perform substitution as per required format, `\n` separates the two lines

Solution with `perl`, entire input file is slurped as one big string and then substitution performed

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/N:;;\n(.*CELLVOICE:(\d+))/N:$2;;\n$1/g' ip.txt
```